# Does Pandas "cross" merge keep order of both left and right?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know if the merge operation using `how="cross"` will keep my lines order on the left and right side, to be more clear, I except something like that :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(["a", "b", "c"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(["1", "2", "3"])

df1.merge(df2, how="cross")

# I except the result to be ALWAYS like this (with 1, 2, 3 repeating) :

0   a   1
1   a   2
2   a   3
3   b   1
4   b   2
5   b   3
6   c   1
7   c   2
8   c   3
```

I tested with few data, but I will have to use billions of rows, thus it's hard to check if the order stays the same.

In [pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html), they say :

> cross: creates the cartesian product from both frames, preserves the order of the left keys.

Left key is preserved, so should I assume right keys order is not ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: "*I assume right keys order is not*" well it is, in the second order of the combinations, always 1/2/3, 1/2/3, 1/2/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the right keys is preserved within each group of left keys. What the documentation describes is that the left keys will be the **primary** order.

Example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(["c", "b", "a"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(["1", "3", "2"])

df1.merge(df2, how="cross")
```

Output:

```
  0_x 0_y
0   c   1   # within a group
1   c   3   # the order is always
2   c   2   # 1 -> 3 -> 2
3   b   1
4   b   3
5   b   2
6   a   1
7   a   3
8   a   2
```

##### how is it done internally?

pandas sets up dummy columns in each DataFrame with a value of 1 and performs an inner merge:

```
    def _create_cross_configuration(
        self, left: DataFrame, right: DataFrame
    ) -> tuple[DataFrame, DataFrame, str, str]:
        """
        Creates the configuration to dispatch the cross operation to inner join,
        e.g. adding a join column and resetting parameters. Join column is added
        to a new object, no inplace modification

        Parameters
        ----------
        left : DataFrame
        right : DataFrame

        Returns
        -------
            a tuple (left, right, how, cross_col) representing the adjusted
            DataFrames with cross_col, the merge operation set to inner and the column
            to join over.
        """
        cross_col = f"_cross_{uuid.uuid4()}"
        how = "inner"
        return (
            left.assign(**{cross_col: 1}),
            right.assign(**{cross_col: 1}),
            how,
            cross_col,
        )
```